# Twitter javascript not functioning?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am using the following code on my website for the twitter widget and it recently stopped functioning. Could anyone tell me why? My website is http://www.lookbookcookbook.com/

Thanks!

```
<div style="top left no-repeat; padding-left: 0px;" id="twitter_div">
<ul id="twitter_update_list"></ul>
<a id="twitter-link" style="display:block;text-align:right;" href="http://twitter.com/lookbookcook" target="_blank">follow us...</a>
</div>
<script src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/lookbookcook.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=5" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I've got it working now.

Instead of using

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/yournamehere.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=5
```

replace it with

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/yournamehere.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=5
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter API has a few breaking changes lately.

First, anywhere is phased out (so if you based it on it, it's natural it stops working).

Second, using any twitter API without explicitly versioning it is also phased out (so you must put `v1` or `v1.1` or something like that in you API calls).

Answer (score 0):

The script you're referencing: https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/lookbookcook.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=5 generates an error.

See if you can generate a new widget [here](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new)